# Can't insert data into database through arrays and implode function using php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert an Html form data into my DB using PHP arrays and implode function. 
The code works fine with no errors and gives me prompt stating values have been inserted. However, when I query into my DB the Values are not present.

#### Html Code:

```
<form action="##"  method="Post">
```

User Name

```
<input type ="text" name="uname" >
```

First Name

```
<input type ="text" name="fname"  >
```

Email

```
<input type ="email" name="email" >
```

submit

```
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

#### PHP CODE :

**Db** Created

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");

$db=mysql_select_db("abcd");
```

Values Passed via **POST** method

```
$a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);

$b=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

$c=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

converting values into an array.

```
$data=array('$a','$b','$c');
```

Usage of implode function for inserting data in feild names in MySql.

```
$f_sql= "'" . implode(',' , array_keys($data)) ."'";
```

Usage of implode function for inserting data in field names. This  will be used for inserting values in Mysql

```
$v_sql="'".implode ("' ,",$data)."'";
```

Finally MySql Command:

```
$sql="insert into pracproj1 ($f_sql) VALUES  ($v_sql)";

if( $sql== true){
    echo "updated";

}

else
    "failed";
```

I get what I **echoed** after I press the **submit** button. But as I said. Real-time values aren't getting updated into my DB.

If, somehow I don't use an **array** or **Implode** function I don't get stuck anywhere.

I am trying to learn few more PHP concepts that I can use with my Html form and that's why I started working with **Implode** and **arrays**.
Kindly help.

Comment: Try printing your sql statement, and run that generated query in your database manually and see if the query is proper ?

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You should also use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: It's pretty hard to follow the code when you chop it up like that. It's better that you post the complete code block. It always helps to see in which context the code is in.

Comment: If I echo $sql; .... I get welcome Asd.
UPDATED.     insert into pracproj1 ('0,1,2') values ('$a' $b' ,$c'')

Comment: Magnus Eriksson . I will get that fixed. I am just using MySql for the time being

Comment: Magnus Eriksson. This is what it is. It's a small form. For learning purpose

Comment: Don't "use it for the time being". Start as you mean to continue.

Comment: @ Strawberry. Will do. Can u fix my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The array of your variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c` would look like this (according to your code):

```
array(3) {
  [0] => string(2) "$a"
  [1] => string(2) "$b"
  [2] => string(2) "$c"
}
```

That is because you're inserting strings into the `array` function. You want to insert the variables. For that, you simply remove the single quotes:

```
$data = array($a, $b, $c);
```

Or, as of PHP 5.4:

```
$data = [$a, $b, $c];
```

However, you also have to make sure the result of `$f_sql` equals the name of the rows of your database table. At this moment it would only return the following string: `0,1,2`. I doubt the names of your rows are 0,1,2.

You could attempt something like the following, if you really want to use arrays:

```
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$b = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

// For older PHP versions we use 'array()' instead of brackets
$insertData = array(
  'uname' => $a,
  'fname' => $b,
  'email' => $c
);

$implodedFields = implode(',', array_keys($insertData));
$implodedValue = implode(',', $insertData);

$sql = "INSERT INTO pracproj1 ($implodedFields) VALUES  ($implodedValue)";
```

Where `'uname'`, `'fname'` and `'email'` in the array should equal the name of your row in the database.

If you're not going to dynamically generate arrays or have any logic to dynamically modify the array and you want static data as I used in my example, I would advise you to write out the row names and echo the variables yourself in the query string for a lighter performance:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pracproj1 (uname, fname, email) VALUES  ($a, $b, $c)";
```

**Important:** Please, make sure to read and consider using MySQLi or PDO and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as told by Magnus in your comments.

Comment: stefan1294. The column names in DB are uname, fname, email.  $insertData = [
  'uname' => $a,
  'fname' => $b,
  'email' => $c];   Gives an error msg= syntax error, unexpected '['. I tried to replace that with parenthesis and curly. But still I gives me an error.

Comment: You are apparently using an outdated PHP version. You could replace the brackets with the `array()` function. Check my modified answer.

Comment: $sql = "insert into pracproj1 (uname, fname, email) VALUES  ($a, $b, $c)";.          It's displaying the input values on my page with echo $sql . However, the values are not getting inserted into DB. MYSQL DB field names==> id (Auto-Increment), uname==> varchar, fname==> varchar, email==> varchar.. Please help as this seems to be a very small issue

Comment: Are you even running the `mysql_query` function to send your query? See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I am indeed running the mysql_query.   
        $result= mysql_query($sql);
        if($result){
      echo "updated";
 
}
else
 "failed";

Comment: The query is fine, it should work. See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e319de/1). It seems like something else is wrong in your code. See the documentation of the `mysql_query` function on how to catch the  `mysql_error` to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank u bro. Your code is now working. Thank u to others as well